# Use Bluebird to handle asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I have been trying to use bluebird in order to run the code below though i get the following error (this must be something easy, though i have not been able to find it): ReferenceError: require is not defined
**What i want to do** is run first the function ajax_call and after it finishes the loop_the_table.

ajax_call_to_php.js

function ajax_and_loop(){

```
      Promise.all(ajax_call).then(loop_the_table).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val.success);
})

   function ajax_call(){

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $.getJSON('php_side.php', function(data) {
           $(data).each(function(key, value) {
               value = value.toString();
               res = value.split(',');
               array_of_people_already_suscribed[row][column++] = res[0];
               array_of_people_already_suscribed[row][column++] = res[1];
               array_of_people_already_suscribed[row][column] = res[2];
               row++;
               column = 0;
                   console.log("kalimera oli mera");
           });
         });
       });
     }

       function loop_the_table(){
         for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){

                   console.log("kalispera oli mera");
             console.log(array_of_people_already_suscribed[i][0]);
             console.log(array_of_people_already_suscribed[i][1]);
             console.log(array_of_people_already_suscribed[i][2]);
           }  
        }  

}
```

In my main html file index.html in part of the head of file is:

```
<script src="js/My_js/ajax_call_to_php.js"></script>
<script src="js/My_js/bluebird.js"></script>
```

where bluebird.js has been downloaded from [here](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird). What am i doing wrong??

Comment: What are those `var fs = require("Bluebird"); Promise.promisifyAll(fs);` lines doing there? Apart from not making sense, there is neither a file system nor a `require` function at the client side.

Comment: Where is `array_of_people_already_suscribed` declared?

Comment: @Bergi i thought of writing that, it is declared in my main file, though please don't give attention to that, what i want is just these two functions to run one after the other (in synchronous way) with bluebird

Comment: @Bergi I know that it is propably not correct in many ways though if you can write a working example and explain what you have done i will be really greatful, bluebird seemed kinda weird to me..

Answer (score 0):

In your code you put:

```
var fs = require("Bluebird");
```

and expression "require" is valid in a node environment for example, but you want to work in a browser so, try to load first bluebird.js and then your custom script:

```
<script src="js/My_js/bluebird.js"></script>
<script src="js/My_js/ajax_call_to_php.js"></script>
```

And delete the required expression because bluebird will be load.

**UPDATED**
I created an example on my github account using bluebird and jquery to simulate your environment: https://github.com/josemato/stackoverflow/tree/master/bluebird-promises-jquery

```
var ajaxSingleCall = function ajaxSingleCall() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.getJSON('php_side.php', function(data) {
            resolve(data);
        }).fail(function(e) {
            reject(e);
        });
    });
};

var ajaxCallMultiple = function ajaxCallMultiple() {
    var promises = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        promises.push(ajaxSingleCall());
    }

    return promises;
};

var loopTheTable = function loopTheTable(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log('timeWait for server', data[i].timeWait);
   }
};

// Example 1: Do only one request and transform server data to array
ajaxSingleCall().then(function(data) {
    console.log('ajaxSingleCall', data);
    return [data];
}).then(loopTheTable);

// Example 2: Do a lot of requests waiting for all
Promise.all(ajaxCallMultiple()).then(function(data) {
    console.log('All multiple data:', data);
    return data;
}).then(loopTheTable);
```

Comment: So these two  `var fs = require("Bluebird");
     Promise.promisifyAll(fs);` should be gone and the rest is correct?

Comment: No, the rest is not ok because you are calling ajax_call like a promise "ajax_call.then" but ajax_call not return a promise. Take a look of an example of how to use native promises (and then you could understand better bluebird): https://github.com/josemato/stackoverflow/blob/master/es-promise-all-no-order/index.js I think that you are using jquery, so, to this example you could use $.deferred and $.when.

Comment: Please check the updated version of my code which does not work either, now producing an unhandled exception.

Comment: Sorry for the late @mpla_mpla I did a custom example for you so I hope that will be enough :) https://github.com/josemato/stackoverflow/blob/master/bluebird-promises-jquery/